# inputStream gives java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, android, inputstream, p12

I have created new thread in my android app to read .p12 file like this:

```
AssetManager am = getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = am.open("C:\\Users\\UkrBikeApp-ff55878cb577.p12");
```

This file exist in directory. But every time I get

> java.io.FileNotFoundException

The simular code works in simple java app without any problems. What is the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `C:\\Users\\UkrBikeApp-ff55878cb577.p12` is a path to a file on a Windows machine. Android is not Windows.

Second, `C:\\Users\\UkrBikeApp-ff55878cb577.p12` is a filesystem path. It is not a path to an asset within your APK, and so `AssetManager` would not know what to do with it anyway.

If you want to package this file in your app:

- Create an `assets/` directory in the appropriate module and source set (e.g., `app/src/main/assets/`)
- Put the file in `assets/`
- Use `open()` on `AssetManager` with the plain filename

Comment: Is there some way to create file from input stream from assets? I need this file to use it in GoogleCredentials.

Comment: @DzouSi: Get the `InputStream`. Create a `FileOutputStream` on some file that you control (e.g., in `getFilesDir()`). Copy the bytes using standard Java I/O.